# Canon ImageCLASS MF232w printer/scanner issues

Tags: canon

Just recently got this printer/scanner combo, but having difficulty getting the scanner function of it to be recognized.   I have installed the "drivers" for the Canon MF230 series for Linux from Canon's web site.

When activating "Direct Connection" on the printer ( wireless ), I can sucessfully print wirelessly from both my laptop and Android phone.

Now, when plugging the printer combo into the laptop directly with a USB cable, the 'lsusb' command shows no difference in its list of connected devices whether the printer is connected or not.  As a result, no scanning software ( SimpleScan or VueScan) recognizes it's even connected.

Anyone have any ideas on this ??

Comment: does the printer have a "Direct Connection (Wired)" separate from its Wireless Direct Connection mechanism?

Comment: Sorry...  It does have a direct connection option in the menu system, but appears to connect to wireless LAN.  The user manual is not very clear.

Comment: It also has Scan->PC1 and Scan->PC buttons on the front panel, which ( appears ) to be configurable.  However, both report back with "Connect the computer", even when directly connected with USB Cable.

Comment: Thomas, the menu system does have "Wired LAN" and "Wireless LAN" options.  But these appear to assume you have a local area network.

Comment: Just double-checked menu settings.  Direct USB connection is not an option.

Comment: Apparently trying to install the bundled CD software through Wine fails, too...  Fails on Installing Drivers".

Comment: You can't use Windows drivers on Linux, even with Wine - they don't have the access to the hardware directly in a way that makes drivers work (Wine isn't Windows, it's just an abstraction layer to make some DLLs work but by leveraging the Linux kernel and translating from Windows syscalls to Linux syscalls, it doesn't let drivers work)